How to add multiple components in forceCommunity:themeLayout body?
I have come across the requirement where I want to use Custom theme and utilize standard userProfile menu component and use custom Navigation bar components. for this I created Aura components that uses Custom theme for community:
Aura:
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Custom Theme Layout">
    <aura:attribute name="header" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="footer" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="backgroundImageURL" type="String" default=""/>
    <div class="custom-wrapper">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>Company Logo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
            <!-- Navigation Menu component -->
            <c:navigationMenu></c:navigationMenu>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="profile-menu-wrapper notifications">
            <forceCommunity:notifications/>
        </div> -->
        <div class="slds-col profileMenuRegion profile-menu-wrapper">
            <!-- User Profile Menu component -->
             {!v.profileMenu}
        </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                {!v.header}
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>Header right content</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            {!v.body}
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-end" style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>Footer left</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                {!v.footer}
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
              <span>Footer right</span>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>

This custom theme layout works fine but problem here is under this tag
<div class="content">
 {!v.body}
</div>

I want to drag drop multiple components. Currently it allows only one components to drag and drop. How can I design a layout in such a way that it allows me to add multiple components which is similar to default theme layout?
What are the possible solutions for this? Any sample code would help here. Also, any consideration while introducing Custom theme layout would be good to know?

I think I have figure it out the rootcause. As per documentation, If I add below CSS to my Aura then it allows me to add more than one components on Content.
.THIS {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

